# Is it possible to use Flume Kafka Source by itself?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

Let's say there are a bunch of producers writing avro records (that have the same schema) into a Kafak Topic.

Can I use Flume Kafka Source to read those records and write them to HDFS.  Even though the records were not published using a Flume Sink?

Comment: Tested this by creating a topic, writing a text message into it and then use flume to read the text message and log it.  It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. In general, what a Kafka consumer can or cannot do is fully independent on who produced the data, but only on the format in which the data has been encoded.

That is the whole point of Kafka and Enterprise Service Bus.

Comment: Thanks, so I don't have follow any special formats, etc.  The Flume Kafka Source will just consume from the topic?

Comment: @hba if you can save the data in the same format of the Kafka messages, you don't have to do anything.